# Jenkins Checking out Repo overtop of Previously Checked Out Code from Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some experience with Jenkins and have started using Jenkinsfiles in the past year, but, I've come across something I haven't been able to explain (or maybe I just haven't come across it yet in the docs).

I have a Jenkinsfile as part of a multi-branch pipeline. In that Jenkinsfile, I basically have this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout(...)
    }

    stage('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'maven:3-alpine'
          args '...'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'mvn -B clean package'
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When executed, the "Build" stage pulls down the branch based on the branch I'm executing the Jenkinsfile in, and overwrites the previously-checked out branch from the "Checkout" stage (which is a different branch).

Now, if I move the "Checkout" steps into the "Build" stage immediately before the Maven sh command, it works, but I notice that the stage is first still pulling down the branch as described above, and then the "Checkout" steps now overwrite that branch.

So, I'm guessing that there's something special about this particular "Build" stage that I'm missing, as I've used this particular methodology before with other projects, the only real differences being in other ones there was no agent specified and it wasn't Java-based (not that I think that has anything to do with it).

Any insight would be appreciated as I'd like to not just apply this "workaround" and rather get it right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline running on any agent available so it pull the repo with the Jenkins file to the randomly selected agent.
Then in the build stage the agent is docker container so I'm guessing the repo need to be pulled again to the container because the container workspace doesn't contain the file from checkout step since it happened on different agent. 
 
You can change the agent of the entire pipeline from any to docker and remove it from build stage I guess this will solve the issue.

Or as you already did move checkout stage to the build stage.

Good luck.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried changing the agent of the entire pipeline and it did what you said. Thank you for explaining it!